# sed property substitution

Tags: sed

I've got a property file where I want to do a property substitution, so I wrote a sed patter to change

```
host = 1234
```

with another value, but when I execute

```
echo "host = 1234" | sed 's/\#*\(host[ \t]*\)\=\([ \t]\d*\)/\1\=\1/g'
```

I got that the substitution is done (host =host) but the \2 atom is also appended to the end of the string (1234). How can I remove it?

```
 `host =host 1234
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to do. What are you trying to make it do? Please give sample input line and desired output line.

Comment: I'd like to change the host = <value> with an host = <newvalue> that for instance can be \1 or a computed one. In the above example the newvalue becomes \1 and the remaining of the line

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that `\d` doesn't do what you think. Use `[0-9]` at least.

You still get `host =host` out, which seems crazy to me.

EDIT:

Okay

```
echo "host = 1234" | sed 's/#*\host[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([0-9]*\)/host = asdf/g'
```

- Why capture 'host' if it's always the same? Just rewrite it.
- Why preserve the exact tab/space information? Just rewrite it.
- Why escape things which are not special?

I hope you get the idea.

But here's what you probably want:

```
sed '/^#/!s/[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\)[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\)/\1 = newvalue/g' input_file
```

This will change `anything = anything` to `anything = newvalue` in non-commented lines of `input_file`. To make it a *specific* key which is replaced by `newvalue`, use:

```
sed '/^#/!s/[ \t]*\(host\)[ \t]*=[ \t]*\([^ \t]*\)/\1 = newvalue/g' input_file
```

to e.g. replace only lines reading `host = anything`.

Comment: @fluca1978: If this answers your question and solves your problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
echo "host = 1234" | cut -d"=" -f 1
```

yields

```
host
```

Then,

```
echo "host = 1234" | cut -d"=" -f 1
```

yields

```
1234
```